# Upgraded to latest NHibernate and FNH - now get SQLite exception "Callback routine requested an abort..."

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to upgrade my WinForms app to the latest versions of NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate, but now I get the SQLite exception **"Callback routine requested an abort"** on the call to BuildSessionFactory.

I have a working sample project that uses the new versions.  I attempted to upgrade my real app by replacing the old NHibernate, FluentNHibernate, and System.Data.SQLite references with the new ones, but that caused the problem.

New versions I'm using:

NHibernate         3.2.0.4000
FluentNHibernate   1.3.0.0
System.Data.SQLite 1.0.76.0
VS 2008            9.0.30729.1 SP
Windows XP SP3 (32 bit)

Comment: a complete Stacktrace could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually traced the problem to having the wrong type of System.Data.SqLite DLL.

Turns out they've added a new version that is not a single DLL deployment - it has dependencies on other DLLs.

This is not clearly explained on the SQLite download page. Also, they use exactly the same names and version numbers, which led to me downloading the wrong one.

Problem went away when I downloaded and referenced the "mixed-mode" assembly.

See my answer to the question [New SQLite Mixed Assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205393/new-sqlite-mixed-assemblies/7988419#7988419) for more details on how to get the "right" one.