# Error creating table in sqlite when changing android to x64 on Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

I had to change android build from x86 to x64, and after doing that an error occurs while trying to create a table in sqllite using xamarin

```
public ObraDao(ISqliteConnectionService connectionService)
        {
            connection = connectionService.GetConnectionAsync();
            if (connection != null)
                CreateTable();
        }

        private async void CreateTable()
        {
            await connection.CreateTableAsync<ViewObra>();
        }
```

```
Error: Could not resolve type with token 0100004c from typeref (expected class 'SQLite.CreateTableResult' in assembly 'SQLite-net, Version=1.5.231.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') assembly:SQLite-net, Version=1.5.231.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null type:SQLite.CreateTableResult member:(null)
```

Comment: A general suggestion - you may not want to make `CreateTable()` `async void`. Have a look at [async/await - when to return a Task vs void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void).

Comment: Thank you, I really didn't realize that.

Comment: @DWojcik Hi , have you solved it ? Here is a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163354/sqlite-dll-for-x86-x64-architectures) , maybe helpful .

Comment: Hi, not yet. Thanks! Sqlite-related packages are already up to date

Comment: I removed the sqlite packages from all projects in the solution and installed it again. It worked...
It seems that solved.